# Im getting the error message Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'product') in React

Tags: reactjs, product

Im trying to insert the below component (Image Gallery) into my product page and its not reading the word product properly so its unable to find the product info which is on my shop page. Can any assist with how I fix this. Thank you in advance

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Imagegallery({product}) {

const prod=product
const highlight = document.querySelector(".gallery-highlight");
const previews = document.querySelectorAll(".image-preview img");


previews.forEach(preview => {
preview.addEventListener("click", function() {
const smallSrc = this.src;
const bigSrc = smallSrc.replace("small", "big");
previews.forEach(preview => preview.className.remove("image-active"));
highlight.src = bigSrc;
preview.className.add("image-active");
});
});

return (
<>
<div className="products">
<div className="product">
<div className="image-gallery">
<img className="gallery-highlight" img src={prod.product.image}
alt={prod.product.name}/>
<div className="image-preview">
<img src={prod.product.image2} className="image-active" />
<img src={prod.product.image3} />

<br />

</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply **useEffect** and **useState**

**PLS NOTE:** if your isn't displaying you should store them in your **PUBLIC FOLDER** for easy access

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Imagegallery({product}) {

const [productData, setProductData] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{
setProductData(product)
}, [product])

const highlight = document.querySelector(".gallery-highlight");
const previews = document.querySelectorAll(".image-preview img");


previews.forEach(preview => {
preview.addEventListener("click", function() {
const smallSrc = this.src;
const bigSrc = smallSrc.replace("small", "big");
previews.forEach(preview => preview.className.remove("image-active"));
highlight.src = bigSrc;
preview.className.add("image-active");
});
});

return (
<>
<div className="products">
<div className="product">
<div className="image-gallery">
<img className="gallery-highlight" img src={productData.image}
alt={productData.name}/>
<div className="image-preview">
<img src={productData.image2} className="image-active" />
<img src={productData.image3} />

<br />

</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</>
);
}
```

if this is your product info in your shop page
**NOTE:** if result is an ARRAY then use at index 0
**for example:** productData[0].image

```
  const [products] = useState(
  {
    category: ART,
    name: 'Original David Bowie Mug Shot Mixed Media Framed 
    Artwork',
    cost: 200,
    image:'images/bowiebig.jpeg',  // this images folder should be store in react Public directory
    image2: 'images/bowiesmall.jpeg', // the same applies here
    image3:'images/bowie2small.jpeg', // the same applies here
    page:'Bowie',
    description: "Original David Bowie Mug Shot Mixed Media 
  Framed Artwork floral painting on wooden canvas with an 
  original pop art style David Bowie Mugshot on top painting is 
   framed with a red baroque style frame including the words 
   deadly flowers bloom around frame",

  },

{
    category: HOME_GARDEN,
    name: 'Blanket',
    cost: 19.99,
    image:
```

Comment: great, thank you. Would I need to use the useeffect anywhere else? The images are stored in my shop.js file do I need to use that there as well? If so, how as at the moment the images arent showing up but the preview box is anm getting this message on console  Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `img`.

Comment: If the images are stored locally, u don't need a useEffect.

Comment: If your images are stored locally in shop.js and you want to use it in another component, you have to export & import it as an object

Comment: thats what I thought I was doing with the {productData.image} etc. Any ideas how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: console.log your productData, reply me with the result, then i will show you how to display your image

Comment: thank you this is what I get when I console Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `img`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: img="true" or img={value.toString()}.
    at img
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at Imagegallery
    at div
    at div
    at Product 
    at div
    at App 
alot of react.DOM messages

Comment: what did you get?

Comment: this site  wont let me add more info than that

Comment: if you want to react to locate your images easily, store them in **public folder** and refer your source as "image.jpeg" for example if stored in public/productimages your image tag should be <img src="productimages/yourimage.jpeg" /> , am sure this works

Comment: pls don't forget to vote & mark this as an helpful answer, if it works

Comment: yeah, but Im trying to use the same space on the webpage for multiple images and info (its a product page ) for each product

Comment: yeah, i know, just stored your images in react public folder